# 12V dc fan motor rpm finding using tacho out

Tags: arduino-uno

I need an Arduino program to find the RPM of a 12V DC fan motor.

I don't want to control the speed. I only want to find the speed of the motor using tacho out.

[image: arduino 3wired fan rpm finding connection]

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Frequency-Counter/

Comment: How is this related to my question? Sorry i am new to this.. help me.. i wanna know only fan motor rpm

Comment: RPM is just frequency. You want to know the frequency of the pulses from the fan. The simplest way is "frequency counting" - counting the number of pulses over a defined time. Frequency = Pulses Per Second.  Pulses Per Second = Revolutions Per Second. Revolutions Per Second * 60 = Revolutions Per Minute.

Comment: do you have a fan that has a tachometer output?

Comment: Thank you buddy....

Comment: @Majenko you should flesh out your answer a little bit and post it as an answer. That way the OP can accept it and we can up-vote it. That link you posted is 90% of the way there.